# Impossible to start Symfony 5 server on Docker container (symfony serve -d)

Tags: symfony, docker-compose, server, dockerfile, localhost

I trying to create Docker container to contenerized my Symfony 5 application.

I create first a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

# Update
RUN apk --no-cache update
RUN apk --no-cache add bash git

# Install Node
RUN apk --no-cache add --update nodejs npm
RUN apk --no-cache add --update python3
RUN apk --no-cache add --update make
RUN apk --no-cache add --update g++

# Install pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Symfony CLI
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

# WORK DIR
COPY . /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN composer update
RUN composer install
RUN npm install

# Start Symfony server on Port 8000
EXPOSE 8000
RUN symfony serve -d
```

Then I created a `docker-compose.yml` file (where I simply redirect port 8000 of the container to port 8080 on my machine).

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    php-fpm:
        container_name: infolea
        build: ./
        ports:
            - 8080:8000
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
```

Then, I build my image `docker-compose build`.
Then, I run my image `docker-compose up -d`.

On my browser, the `localhost:8080` link doesn't display anything.
Then I restart the symfony server by typing `symfony serve -d` on the terminal of my container and on `localhost:8080` I can see my application working.

Something is weard, is that when I verified if my server is not started yet on my docker container terminal, I got this :

[docker container terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYKvX.png)

What i want, it's to start my Symfony server dirrectly, without retapping `symfony serve -d`.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CMD istead of RUN

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/symfony", "local:server:start" , "--port=8000", "--no-tls"]
```

see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd